# im trying to call a razor

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

i try but the call never worked can you helpme
with a post related or a solution please i'm
stacked with this to go on, i'm working with vs 2022

i try this but the call never worked

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfZGI.png)

i want to run this

```
    
        public ActionResult GetItems(string name)
        {
            return new JsonResult(name);
            
        }
```

it is located in /Admin/Rpouters/Router/GetItems

Comment: i will prove it wright now...

Comment: hi, Yiyi you that work in html but not in razor ...!

Comment: Hi,I have updated my answer with razor page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a `List<SelectListItem>` type data in your action,and you need to pass the selected value to the action.here is a demo:
html:

```
<select id="IdSelectIdEmpleado" onchange="adddata()">
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
    <option value="five">5</option>

</select>
<select id="mydrop"></select>
```

js:

```
function adddata() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { name: $("#IdSelectIdEmpleado").val() },
                    url: '/Admin/Rpouters/Router/GetItems',
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            $("#mydrop").append("<option value='" + data[i].value + "' selected>" + data[i].text + "</option>");
                        }
                    }
                    })
            }
```

action:

```
[HttpPost("/Admin/Rpouters/Router/GetItems")]
        public ActionResult GetItems(string name)
        {
            return new JsonResult(new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value="1", Text=name+1}, new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = name + 2 } });

        }
```

result:
[image]

**Update:**

Since you are using razor page,here is a razor page demo:

Router.cshtml:

```
<select id="IdSelectIdEmpleado" onchange="adddata()">
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
    <option value="five">5</option>

</select>
<select id="mydrop"></select>
<button onclick="DeleteHourLine()">button</button>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@section Scripts{

    <script>
        function adddata() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '?handler=GetItems',
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                data: { name: $("#IdSelectIdEmpleado").val() },
                success: function(data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $("#mydrop").append("<option value='" + data[i].value + "' selected>" + data[i].text + "</option>");
                    }
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("fail");
                }
            })
        }

    </script>
}
```

Router.cshtml.cs:

```
public class RouterModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet() {
        
        }
        public IActionResult OnPostGetItems(string? name)
        {
            return new JsonResult(new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = name + 1 }, new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = name + 2 } });

        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Yiyi You foe the answer but the issue still do not reach to [HttpPost("/Admin/Routers/Router/GetItems")]

Comment: can you helpme please the project is in razor 2022, i do exactly as you post it

Comment: Yiyi You please helpme...!

Comment: click F12 and check the Network,when you change the selected data,is the request status 200?

Comment: i create atest project and i put thie in the index

Comment: now tie location is in the Page/Index/GetItems

Comment: i preciate that you use your Time just for help me. Thank you very mych...

Comment: the status code is 400

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: I have updated my answer with a razor page demo.